# Gravidade com a biblioteca "physics" corona SKD (ERROR)

Tags: lua, jogos

Estou resolvendo um exercício da faculdade em corona SDK na realização de um pequeno jogo, porém estou com um pequeno problema na hora em que a bolinha vai cair de "cima" pela segunda vez. A questão é que eu preciso que caem as bolinhas do topo do celular para poder desviar com meu objeto "personagem" que é no entanto um quadrado azul. A primeira vez quando é executado o programa, a bolinha consegue cair normalmente, e assim que ela toca ao chão ela apaga e cria-se outra nova no topo do celular, porém ela não aplica a gravidade para que possa cair, o corona gera o seguinte erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o desenho da bolinha juntamente com a gravidade aplicada, e a chamada do método de desenho da bolinha para ela seja criada novamente.

```
--Personagem
quad[1] = display.newRect(200,400,50,50)
quad[1]:setFillColor(0,0,255)
quad[1].myName = "personagem"

-- bola
local function desenhaBolinha()
    local bola = {}
    local raio = math.random(20,40)
    local bolaX = math.random(0,320)
    bola[1] = display.newCircle(bolaX,raio,raio)
    bola[1]:setFillColor(255,0,0)
    bola[1].anchorX = 0
    bola[1].anchorY = 0
    bola[1].y = 10
    bola[1].myName = "bola"
    phy.addBody(bola[1], "dynamic")
    return (bola[1])
end
circ[1] = desenhaBolinha()
-- chão 
quad[7] = display.newRect(0,500,700,10)
quad[7]:setFillColor(255,255,255)
quad[7].myName = "chao"

-- FISICA
local function grav()
    phy.setGravity(0,20)
    phy.addBody(circ[1], "dynamic")
    phy.addBody(quad[7], "static")
    phy.addBody(quad[1], "dynamic")
end
grav()
```

Método criado abaixo do código postado acima, para que sejam feitas as verificações de colisão e recriação do objeto "bolinha":

```
local function colisao(e)
    --detecta colisao 
    if(e.phase == "began") then
        print("began: " .. e.object1.myName .. " com " .. e.object2.myName)
    elseif e.phase == "ended" then
        print("ended: " .. e.object1.myName .. " com " .. e.object2.myName)
    end

    if(e.phase == "began" and e.object1.myName == "bola" and e.object2.myName == "personagem") then
        text[2].text =  text[10] - 1
    end

    if(e.phase == "began" and e.object1.myName == "bola" and e.object2.myName == "chao") then
        circ[2] = e.object1
        circ[2]:removeSelf()
        circ[2] = desenhaBolinha()
    end

end
```

Se alguém puder dar uma força! Agradeço.

Answer (score 1):

Várias funções de física não podem ser chamadas durante um evento de colisão, exatamente como a mensagem de aviso diz. É necessário executar esse tipo de operação após um temporizador muito curto (10 a 50 milissegundos) para que a operação ocorra na próxima etapa do quadro do tempo de execução, após o mecanismo de física ter feito seus cálculos para a colisão e assim por diante.

Outra coisa a se fazer, é colocar o código de física na função Show, caso esteja usando composer.